# python Database Connection in function

Tags: python, oracle

I try to create a function for database connection in python. But this is now working.
Here is my code for the definition.

```
def connect():
    dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn(host='MYHOST', sid='DEVPRON', port=1521)
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user='root', password='***', dsn=dsn)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    return [cur,conn]
```

I return conn and cur every time i call the connect function.
so here is my code when iam calling the function

```
connect()[0].execute("insert into tbluser (fullname,nickname) values ('" + fname + "', '" + nname + "') ")
connect()[1].commit()
```

when i run this no error occur, but when i check the database, there is no inserted row. please help. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each time you call your connect function you are creating a new connection to the database server.  So, your first call executes a query.  The second call gives you a *new* connection.  You're committing with this new connection, but there have been no changes.  Try this instead:

```
def connect():
    dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn(host='MYHOST', sid='DEVPRON', port=1521)
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user='root', password='***', dsn=dsn)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    return cur, conn

cur, conn = connect()
cur.execute("insert into tbluser (fullname,nickname) values ('" + fname + "', '" + nname + "') ")
conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

using sqlalchemy also you can connect database from python.  Here is the code

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('oracle://host:port/database', echo=True)
conn = engine.connect()
result = conn.execute(query)
```